# Wordpress Multisite blogs not working after domain swap

Tags: multisite, database, subdomains

After I swapped over my domains and updated every instance of the old domain in the database and everything else in this guide:

https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/

My main domain works, but none of the subdomains do any more. Dashboard or otherwise. Any advice?

Main domain here: http://maaa.org (my sub domains: eusa.maaa.org, neh.maaa.org)

**UPDATE**

I figured out the issue. Since we weren't managing the domain we had it pointed via an A record only and therefore couldn't just have subdomains on the fly. So I requested the person managing the domains to create these subdomains for me on their end.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Since we weren't managing the domain we had it pointed via an A record only and therefore couldn't just have subdomains on the fly. So I requested the person managing the domains to create these subdomains for me on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied and modified the specified lines from your `wp-config.php` from old site to the new site?

The code should look something like this

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yourdomain.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```